# Solution to my "Work From Home" Office Phone Setup

Tags: headset, cable, audio-adapters

My job uses a cloud-based PBX system that I can access from home by dialing into it with my cell phone. I, like most of the modern world, no longer use a landline in my home. I have an iPhone 7 plus with **a lightning connector**, and I need to make this connect to a **Jabra 860 amplifier** in the simplest method possible **via rj9 connection** as seen here:

[image]

*(Background Info) Typically I get audio from my work PC through USB. However, while working remotely I am required to call-in because I am unable to use this USB audio as our PBX system doesn't have our IP addresses whitelisted to be able to connect remotely from our PCs. While we are connecting to our servers through VPN, that connection isn't using the whitelisted IP that we need either.*

First, I have already purchased a splitter that allows me to both charge my phone and connect a 3.5 mm audio cable. So now I am needing a **3.5mm (male) to rj9 (male) cable** that will connect the iPhone splitter and the amplifier. But I am not having much success finding this. I have found other solutions that allow a 3.5mm to Jabra QC (Quick Connect), but that would require me to bypass the amplifier altogether and connect straight to my headset and I am not sure how I feel about this.

So far, I have found a 3.5 mm (male) to rj9 (female), but this would then require me to purchase yet another cable: rj9 (male) to rj9 (male). This would make 3 separate cables I would have to use just to get to the amplifier. I am afraid the more complicated I make this connection the more sources of failure I may encounter - or I may just run into degrading quality due to the length and many connections.

In the end, I am looking for 1 of the following.

- A cable solution that would allow me to get my 3.5 mm iPhone splitter to RJ9. Then I can use an existing headset that already has a connection from the amplifier, OR
- A new headset if the above is not possible. Headset should be decent quality, and contain all of the following features:

  - 1 ear (mono) on-the-ear speaker *(over the ear may be okay, but not preferred. In-the-ear is a no go)*
  - Extended, rotating microphone (this is why I am not using the iPhone headset)
  - Some level of noise cancellation / unidirectional microphone
  - NOT wireless *(although this would be a very easy connection to my iPhone)*
  - I also have a lightning to lightning (charger) / lightning (audio) splitter. So I am okay with a headset that has a lightning (male) connector or a 3.5 mm (male) connector

This will be a solution that will be used for a short period of time and probably never touched again. So my preferred budget is around $50 USD, but that's negotiable.

Also, I am not looking to splice my own cables.

Comment: Does the 3.5mm connector have to be [TRRS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phone_connector_(audio)#TRRS_standards) to allow both mic and audio through? Does your iPhone charging splitter provide the TRRS pins too?

Comment: @Romen Yes, TRRS is required and I made sure to verify that the splitter supported TRRS prior to purchasing.

Comment: It seems that the Jabra amplifier is purpose built to replace telephone handsets, which have bad line quality in the first place and varying microphone impedances. Your iPhone may already provide many of the capabilities that this "amplifier" provides, especially when it comes to the software enhancements.

Comment: @Romen that may be the case, but this amplifier has a switch for handset and PC comms. So normal calls will be switched to the handset (iphone) and when that’s not in use it will be switched over to PC audio - for video conferences my company holds daily for example. It’s also nice to have a dedicated mute button instead having to wake my screen if mute is required.

Comment: If you really need to do it with all 3.5mm and can't find the converter you want, consider that a 3-way switch for 3.5mm TRRS would allow you to switch between the Phone, PC, and "off" (not connected third jack).